# Си.Сортировка бинарными вставками.Как посчитать количество перестановок и сравнений

Tags: c, сортировка, insert

Как подсчитать количество перестановок и сравнений правильно?Мне кажется, что я ошиблась.Потому что график выглядит довольно странно. (1 столбец - кол-во элементов в массиве , 2 столбец - среднее значение суммы перестановок и сравнений на массиве из n эл-тов)
Помогите пожалуйста
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
            swaps=0;
            comps=0;
            for ( i = 1; i < n-1; i++){
                x=a[i];
                if (x<a[i-1]){
                    ++comps;
                    left=0;
                    right= i-1;}
                while(left<right){
                    sred=(left+right)/2;
                    if (a[ sred]<x){
                        ++comps;
                        left = sred+1;
                    }
                    else right=sred;
                }
                for ( j = i-1; j < right-1; j++){
                    a[j+1]=a[j];
                    a[right]=x;
                ++swaps;    
                }
```

upd:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    FILE *f=fopen("stat25.csv","w");
    int n=100;
    int i,s;
    while (n<=10000){
    int st=0;
    for (s=0;s<5;s++)
    {
        int *a;
        a=(int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
        time_t invocation_time = time(NULL);
        srand(invocation_time);
        int k;
        for (k=0;k<n;k++)
        {
            a[k] = rand() % 50;
        }
        int j,comps,swaps,x,right,left,sred;
        swaps=0;
        comps=0;
        for ( i = 1; i < n-1; i++){
            x=a[i];
            if (x<a[i-1]){
                ++comps;
                left=0;
                right= i-1;}
            while(left<right){
                sred=(left+right)/2;
                if (a[ sred]<x){
                    ++comps;
                    left = sred+1;
                }
                else right=sred;
            }
            for ( j = i-1; j < right-1; j++){
                a[j+1]=a[j];
                a[right]=x;
            ++swaps;    
            }
            
        }
    st+=swaps + comps;  
    free(a);
    }
        
    st=st/5;
    fprintf(f,"%d ; %d\n", n , st);
    if (n<1000){
        n+=100;}
    else {n+=1000;} 
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

upd 2

```
swaps=0;
comps=0;
for ( i = 1;  i < n; i++) 
++comps;
if (a[i-1] > a[i]){
    x = a[i];
    left = 0;  
    right = i-1;  
    do {
        sred = (left + right)/2;
        ++comps;    
        if  (a[sred] < x ) left = sred + 1;  
        else  right = sred - 1;      
    } while (left <= right);
    for ( j = i-1; j>=left; j--)
        a[j+1] = a[j];  
    a[left] = x;
     ++swaps; 
    }
```

Comment: На всякий случай... А сколько различных массивов одного размера вы сортировали для получения среднего?

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов 5 раз для каждого .(для 100, для 200 и т.д.)

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Вся проблема в неправильном подсчете перестановок и обменов, насколько я понимаю..Но как исправить, пока не очень понимаю..

Comment: Конечно, я могу ошибаться, но может все же недостаточно попыток? Попробуйте сделать для каждого размера хотя бы  раз по 100-150... Не забывая каждый раз генерировать новый массив. Он же у Вас рандомом заполняется, верно? А значит, одна неудачная генерация с аномально малым количеством перестановок может сильно исказить результат

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Всё верно.Ну насколько я понимаю, график должен иметь экспоненциальный рост, но точно уж не такой..Пробовала еще раз.Что-то подобное всё равно выходитТ.е. ошибки в подсчете перестановок и сравнений нет?..Не может такого быть..

Comment: Да, на сколько понимаю, характер графика должен быть примерно такой, но на малых количествах повторов могут быть практически произвольные искажения. Что же касается самого подсчета, то, мне кажется, все правильно. Хотя, безусловно, я могу ошибаться.

Comment: А вы уверены, что ваш код работает правильно? Не могли бы вы выложить полный код функции сортировки? Чтобы можно было запустить у себя. Так же в цикле `while` у вас `comps` увеличивается только если `a[sred] < x` а если он `>=` то сравнения не происходило?

Comment: сравнения считать надо все, а не половину. *перед if а не если равно true*

Comment: @ПавелЕриков вопрос дополнила кодом.

Comment: @AlexGlebe где именно?Приведите фрагмент с исправлениями :)

Comment: везде где `++comps;` надо это делать **перед** `if`

Comment: У вас код по идее не рабочий, например если `x >= a[i - 1]`, то `left` будет не проинициализирована (в ней будет мусор), как минимум все что ниже `if(x < a[i - 1])` нужно вставить внутрь `if`, но у вас точно не одна ошибка.

Comment: @AlexGlebe перенесла их перед if-ми , теперь получился график "прямой"

Comment: @ПавелЕриков можете привести фрагмент кода с правками , где именно сортировка, пожалуйста?

Comment: @LusindaBabaika проще будет вам погуглить рабочее решение (это очень легко найти в интернете), а не искать ошибки.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Буду благодарна за источники с рабочими решениями, хахах

Comment: @LusindaBabaika да чтож такое, в гугле пишите "сортировка бинарными вставками c++" (я знаю, что тег c, но в плане реализации алгоритма отличий 0) и первая же [ссылка](https://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread549088.html) выдает вам алгоритм. Теперь осталось где нужно расставить ++comps и ++swaps и получить результат. Я проверил код по ссылке и выдает нужный экспоненциальный рост. Но его писал так же студент, так что можно поискать источники и по надежнее.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Здорово, спасибо.Но я до сих пор не знаю куда ставить свопы......

Comment: @LusindaBabaika в коде по ссылке есть 2 `if` перед ними делаете `comps` думаю это логично. А где `a[...] = ...` происходит там считаете `swaps` по идее и это логичною

Comment: @ПавелЕриков отредактировала вопрос.Теперь так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну основы программирования то надо знать. `{}` для `for` нужно написать же. И в последнем моем комментарии я писал, что "*где a[...] = ... происходит там считаете swaps*". Но вы же добавили `++swaps` только после `a[left] = x`, а как же `a[j + 1] = a[j]`?

```
int swaps = 0, comps = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    ++comps;
    if (a[i - 1] > a[i]) {
        x = a[i];
        left = 0;
        right = i - 1;
        do {
            sred = (left + right) / 2;
            ++comps;
            if (a[sred] < x) left = sred + 1;
            else  right = sred - 1;
        } while (left <= right);
        for (int j = i - 1; j >= left; j--) {
            ++swaps;
            a[j + 1] = a[j];
        }
        ++swaps;
        a[left] = x;
    }
}
```

Удачи при защите этой работы, она вам пригодится!